# Is it possible to use NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore within the iOS 7 or iOS 8 Simulator?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, icloud

I'm trying to test an app that uses iCloud key-value storage. Everything is working on a physical device, but the key-value storage doesn't save anything using the simulator.

From what I understand [based on this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ides/conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html), iCloud testing is possible on the simulator and this should work. (btw, I've configured iCloud on the simulator)

I'm using Xamarin / Monotouch with the following code:

```
var store = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.DefaultStore;
store.SetString ("TestKey", "test123");
store.Synchronize ();
```

When reading the value immediately afterward or later, the value is always null.

```
var store = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.DefaultStore;
var testValue = store.GetString ("TestKey");
//*** testValue always null using the simulator ***
```

Is it possible to test iCloud key-value storage in the iOS simulator?

Comment: I haven't used Xamarin, but I know it works when I run similar Objective-C code in the simulator.